# Windows Phone multi-touch

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone, multi-touch

I would like to create in my Windows Phone Silverlight application two controls and start my timer when both of them are pressed. I tried to do this with MouseLeftButtonDown event, but it does not support multitouch. Tap event is fired after control is released so it is not what I want. Hold event is fired after one second after control is pressed - I would like to get event immediately when both controls are pressed in the same time.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried using the "PointerEntered" and "PointerExited" events? Since there's no way to "hover" over anything with touch they will fire whenever something is touched/not touched.

Comment: I do not have those events. Are they standard events in Windows Phone apps?

Comment: Look at the `Manipulation*` events

Comment: Manipulation events work the same as MouseLeftButton(Down/Up) - when I click control and hold it ManipulationStarted for this control is fired correctly, but then when I press second control (still holding first control), ManipulationStarted for that control is not fired.

Comment: If the ```Manipulation*``` events aren't working for you, perhaps the lower-level ```TouchPoint``` might help? http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahakgupta/touch-events-in-windows-phone-7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Fabian .
I used TouchPoint

I did something like this and it works:

```
TouchPoint primaryTouchPoint = e.GetPrimaryTouchPoint(mainGrid);
TouchPointCollection touchPoints = e.GetTouchPoints(mainGrid);

foreach (TouchPoint tp in touchPoints)
{
    var controlPosition = myControl.TransformToVisual(Application.Current.RootVisual).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
    if (tp.Action == TouchAction.Down && tp_is_in_myControl)
        do_something;

}
```